# Operation timed out while switching to webview(NewTab) context in Appium 1.13 IOS 12.3.1

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-ios

After switching to native popup Allow is clicked then it will not switch to webview and control doesn't go to next tab. I am getting Native, Webview_4,Webview_5 like wise.

Error stack trace:

```
May 28, 2019 9:36:30 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //button[@class='little130 blue']) org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Did not get any response after 20s Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z' System info: host: 'local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c1a:bce1:50e1:ac1d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.4', java.version: '12' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver Capabilities {appiumVersion:
1.9.1, autoAcceptAlerts: true, autoDismissAlerts: true, autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: XCUITest, browserName: Safari, databaseEnabled: false, deviceName:TS, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: falsenetworkConnectionEnabled: false, newCommandTimeout: 2000,platform: MAC, platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 12.2, safariAllowPopups: false, startIWDP: true, takesScreenshot: true, udid: ****..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour: true, unhandledPromptBehavior: true, webStorageEnabled: false, webkitResponseTimeout: 20000, xcodeOrgId: BYKRN84M2R, xcodeSigningId: iPhone Developer} Session ID: fc7d6ca1-3901-4fb0-a001-69ff9a499308
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[@class='little']} at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) atjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)atjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158) at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
```

the used following code but it doesn't work

```
Set<String> strcont=null; strcont=driver.getcontextHandles(); 
For(String s: strcont) {
  if(s.contains(WEBVIEW)) {
    driver.context(s); 
  } 
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
After clicking the "popup" button again switch to webview,give break inside the condition find the below code

Set<String> strcont=null; strcont=driver.getcontextHandles(); 
For(String s: strcont) {
  if(s.contains(WEBVIEW)) {
    driver.context(s); 
    break;
  } 
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Or go with this capabilities=>   caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true)

Comment: using this below modified method:
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
// System.out.println(contextNames.toString());
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
if (contextName.contains(viewType)) {

if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
System.out.println(contextNames);
System.out.println(contextNames.toArray()[contextNames.toArray().length - 1].toString());
BasePage._driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[contextNames.toArray().length - 1].toString());
} else {
BasePage._driver.context(contextName);
}
}

Comment: System.out.println(contextNames); [NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_6,WEBVIEW_7]
System.out.println(contextNames.toArray()[contextNames.toArray().length - 1].toString());  : WEBVIEW_7

getting the same exception error

Comment: error is showing in this line :  BasePage.driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[contextNames.toArray().length - 1].toString());

Comment: hi dude actually I didn't get can u please elaborate in words